# Django Postgres database with multiple schema. How to add records to specific schema through shell

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, multi-tenant, django-filter

Iam currently working on django multi tenant using shared database with multiple schema approach.
How can I add records to specific schema through shell.How can I get the specific schema database objects in views.py

In django we can get a model obect using `Model.objects.all` but in case of multiple schema how can i get the specific schema model object. Using SQL we can have `SELECT * FROM [Schema].Model`.
How can we achieve this in django ORM?

Comment: maybe this helps: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/208826/django-postgres-multiple-schema

Answer (score 1):

After lot of research I got an answer.

```
from django.db import connection
connection.schema_name = 'Your schema name'
```

Then filter the models it will only show the records in that schema.
Suppose after assiging the schema `connection.schema_name = 'Your schema name'` and if we filter the User model `User.objects.all()` it will only shows the user objects in that schema.

If we set a schema name which is not present yet like  `connection.schema_name = 'Schema name which is not present'` then we we filter the model it will always shows the `public` schema records.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [django-tenants](https://django-tenants.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) you can use `tenant_command` to run a command on a specific schema (ie. tenant). You can find the `tenant_command` documentation [here](https://django-tenants.readthedocs.io/en/latest/use.html#tenant-command).

In your case, the command you're looking for is the following:

```
python3 manage.py tenant_command shell --schema [SCHEMA_NAME]
```

This will allow you to query and create objects that solely exists in the database schema of the provided tenant.